# populate HTML field from Hidden Field Value

Tags: html, wordpress, hiddenfield

I have 2 forms. On the first form I want to place the username in a hidden field. Then, on the second form I want to use that user name as the value of username field.

```
<form method="POST" name="form1" id="don_form1">
        userName:<input type="text" name="uname">
        Email:<input type="text" name="fname">
        password:<input type="password" name="fname">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn1" id="btn1"/>
</form>

<form method="POST" name="form2" id="don_form2">
        userName:<input type="text" name="uname">
        Age:<input type="text" name="fname">
        Country:<input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn2" id="btn2"/>
</form>
```

So, on the second form I don't want the user to his user name again, as this field should be populated on its own. The forms are on 2 different pages of Wordpress.

Comment: You need to store the data somewhere

Comment: I want to store data in Hidden Variable and I have no choice other than Hidden Fields, How to use Hidden Fields for this purpose

Comment: You can use type="hidden"

Comment: @AliGajani plz provide an example or tutorial if you have,

Comment: There is one possibility. If user submit first form then after page redirects to second form page. If you can do something this type. Here you don't need to take user name in hidden value or somewhere store the data.

Comment: dear at first, first form is filled and the clicking on Submit, it goes to 2nd form for more Input fields,

Comment: Okay its simple. you can form submit through post method and then redirects second form page. Then you will get user name using this $_POST['uname'] on second form page

Comment: I am using Wordpress for Development,